# mysqli_fetch_row only works for the first row

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my third day doing SQL, I'm sure it's something small.

I have this code. $con is my variable for the SQL connection.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE active='y'")); $i++)
{
    echo '<div class="dottedBox">User: '.mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT poster FROM offers WHERE active='y'"))[$i]."<br>
    Has: ".mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT haveamt FROM offers WHERE active='y'"))[$i]." ".mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT have FROM offers WHERE active='y'"))[$i].'<br>
    Wants: '.mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT wantamt FROM offers WHERE active='y'"))[$i].' '.mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT want FROM offers WHERE active='y'"))[$i].'</div><br>';
}
```

The first item outputs fine. However, every subsequent item causes the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/civ/index.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/civ/index.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/civ/index.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/civ/index.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/civ/index.php on line 8
```

Running `SELECT * FROM offers;` returns this in mysql (I'm using Debian):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM offers;
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| poster   | have      | haveamt | want      | wantamt | offerid | active |
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| minicl55 | gfdsafdsa |       3 | fdsafdsa  |       2 |       1 | y      |
| minicl55 | jklgdsa   |     324 | jfklsdjkl |    4522 |       2 | y      |
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I have two questions:

- Why doesn't it output correctly
- How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code is rerunning the SQL query in each for loop. It seems you're even trying to fetch each column individually with new queries then - instead of just fetching an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the database for every value in the loop. You should only need to query the database once and then loop through the results to display them.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE active='y'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<div class="dottedBox">User: '.$row['poster']."<br>
    Has: ".$row['haveamt']." ".$row['offers'].'<br>
    Wants: '.$row['wantamt'].' '.$row['offers'].'</div><br>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thank you. By the way, you have an extra { on the third (or fourth depending on how you like to write code). I can't edit it because it's less than 7 chars